# Responsively rescale and position image over responsive element

Tags: html, css

Example to best describe question:

I have an image, lets call it *background* (blue in example). In this example the image is

- 2000px wide / 1000px high
- has `width: 100%` set and will rescale with the browser window.

[image: Background]

I also have another image, let's call it *green*. It's a square which is

- 200px x 200px (width is 10% of the size of the *background*).

[image: Green]

What I want to achieve is that I want *green* to rescale and reposition accordingly and fully cover the pink target position of the *background*, regardless of current viewport width (in other words: it should be "responsive").

The rescaling part is easy, as it's just to set the width to 10%. The positioning is a harder nut to crack. The following code is as far as I get. As I'm using `position: absolute` I'm removing the element from it's natural flow and `top: 40%` will be `40% of 0` and the green square will stay at the top.

Same example code is available as a CodePen for easier editing: http://codepen.io/emiloberg/pen/vGdNaX?editors=1100#

Is this simply not possible with pure CSS? If not, one possible workaround could be to use the `image` element of a `svg`.

```css
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
}

.bg {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
}

.green {
  position: absolute;
  width: 10%;
  left: 60%;
  top: 40%; /* This isn't working */
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <img class="bg" src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/3378286/solayout/bg.png">
  <img class="green" src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/3378286/solayout/green.png">
</div>
```

*(I had a hard time finding a suitable title for this question. Feel free to edit it)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Explanation: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp

CSS:

```
.bg {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Way to easy considering my headache! Cheers!